# Metoer 1.2.1: db.find().count() returns 1 or 0 on the client side but returns correct value on terminal

Tags: meteor, client

For my Meteor Project running on Meteor 1.2.1 I have run into a mongodb problem on the client-side. Here is a snippet of the code in the mongo db terminal.

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.likes.find().count()
```

When I run this on the terminal it returns the correct answer of 87. However when I write a helpers function on my client side and try to display the information on my HTML I get a 0. Here is a snippet of my HTML:

```html
<span class="label label-danger">{{ numLikes }}</span>
```

and my js:

```js
'numLikes': function () {
    var countLikes = Likes.find().count();
    return countLikes;
}
```

this is what I get:(answer is in the red box of the image) [Click here to view the Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ov0O.png)

Here is all my server-side code regarding my database:

This code is in the both folder:

```js
Likes = new Mongo.Collection("likes");
```

And my code to publish this database is in my servers/publications folder

```js
Meteor.publish('likes', function () {
    return Likes.find();
});
```

Comment: Are you subscribing to the publication?

Comment: Please post more of the js-code of the template, especially onCreated

Comment: Did you subscribe to collection on  onCreated method??? If not then you must subscribe to collection.

Comment: Oh my god! I dont have a onCreated function. so i should create a onCreated function and add a subscribe method inside?